# django admin styling is corrupted

Tags: django, admin

I have just started learning Django and when I got to the admin page it appears to be corrupted, no style. I tried collectstatic which gave me an error, I tried to alter static_root but my settings.py does not have it. I tried to reload the page several times with Fn F5 but it did not help. I found some suggestions on the internet but they seem to be a bit too advanced for me, I don't want to make things worse. Is there something not too advanced you could recommend? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Be sure you have set DEBUG=True is settings.py otherwise Debug Server will not serve static files.

Comment: If you are afraid of adding variables in settings, maybe it is a good call to do some programming/django tutorials first?